# API getting called 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing code for a component in a react, where I need to call an API, I used useEffect hook with an empty dependency array, but the API is getting called 2 times. I cannot figure out why.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const ResMenu = () => {

  const fetchData = async () => {
    let data = await fetch(
        "https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/pl?page-type=REGULAR_MENU&complete-menu=true&lat=28.7040592&lng=77.10249019999999&restaurantId=622616&catalog_qa=undefined&submitAction=ENTER"
      );
     const json = await data.json();
     const restaurants = json?.data?.cards[2]?.groupedCard?.cardGroupMap?.REGULAR?.cards[2]?.card?.card?.itemCards;
     console.log(restaurants);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("called");
      fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="res-menu">
      Res Menu
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResMenu;
```

Here, "called" is printed once only but the restaurants are printed twice, everytime the component is re-rendered after the initial render.

By initial render, I mean when I refresh the page at first, the restaurant data is printed only single time. But then if I do some changes in code or just on autosave, the console gets first cleared and then restaurants are printed twice and "called" is printed once.

Comment: just remove React.strictMode from index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

To address the problem, you need to take out the <React.strict> from the entry point.